# jQuery, delay ctrl+c to focus and highlight text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's possible to prevent ctrl+c from working on websites with `jQuery`. So this led me to think that maybe it is possible to pause or interrupt the process so you can focus and highlight some text, and then let it continue.

The idea would be to specify what is sent to the clipboard when ctrl+c is pressed. So the flow would be:

1. User presses ctrl+c.
2. jQuery intercepts the key press.
3. jQuery adds and then highlights some text on the page.
4. jQuery then lets the ctrl+c process continue so the highlighted text is now copied.

Sound possible?

Comment: My initial gut feeling is that this isn't possible. I don't know for sure, though, so only posting this as a comment.

Comment: Sounds like an evil thing to do.

Comment: Are you trying to add some text to that which is placed in the clipboard?

Comment: Trying to make it easy for a end user to copy a section of my site to the clipboard. Dragging to highlight a section to copy, although to us seem trivial, to an every day internet user it can be a barrier. Especially for us and our web app. It would be good if we could just show the user a pop-up that said press ctrl+c to have "whatever" copied to your clipboard...

Comment: You may provide a "copy to clipboard" button, as can be seen on many programming blogs just next to code snippets...

Comment: @Tallmaris - How does this work? Does it just highlight the relevant text, or odes it actually copy the text to the clipboard? I was under the impression you were not able to copy stuff directly to the users clipboard with the use the flash?

Comment: There are some newspaper websites that intercept a copy operation and append a copyright/citation to the text in the clipboard.

Comment: @superphonic: Implementing a feature with a keypress that works contrary to the same keypress in every other software alive is not making it _easier_ for "an every day internet user". They know what highlighting and copying does, so let them do that in the manner that Microsoft products have taught them, instead of redefining what Ctrl+C does and confusing the heck out of everybody.

Comment: You can not interrupt the copy event. You can interrupt the text selection and append something to it. If you want your users to copy a  predefined text you either have to preselect it for them before or use something like ZeroClipboard and copy it to the clipboard for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. In the end I chose to have a button click open a light box containing the html to be copied, and then automatically highlights it. The user then just has to hit ctrl+c. The following is the code I found to do this, it highlights everything within the specified element, images, links, text etc..

```
function SelectText(element) {
var text = document.getElementById(element);
if ($.browser.msie) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
} else if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
} else if ($.browser.safari) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.selectAllChildren(text);
}
}
```

Thanks